# as_json not calling as_json on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with data that should never be included when it is rendered as json.  So I implemented the class' as_json method to behave appropriately.  The problem is when other models with associations with this model render json, my custom as_json is not being called.

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dog

  def as_json(options={})
    puts "Owner::as_json"
    super(options)
  end  
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner

  def as_json(options={})
    puts "Dog::as_json"
    options[:except] = :secret
    super(options)
  end  
end
```

> Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
>   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > d = Dog.first
>     => `#<Dog id: 1, owner_id: 1, name: "Scooby", secret: "I enjoy crapping everwhere"`>
>   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > d.as_json
>   Dog::as_json
>    => {"dog"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Scooby", "owner_id"=>1}}
>   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > d.owner.as_json(:include => :dog)
>   Owner::as_json
>    => {"owner"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Shaggy", :dog=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Scooby", "owner_id"=>1, "secret"=>"I enjoy crapping everwhere"}}}

Thanks for the help

Comment: I have this problem as well, while using Mongoid on Rails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/576) in Rails. (The issue is marked closed due to the migration to Github issues from the previous bug tracker, but it's still a problem as of Rails 3.1.)

Comment: Yeah, the migration to Github issues broke all existing links. :( Fixed.

Comment: For those looking here for a quick work around, it's burried in the comments, but basically, you can work around by renaming your custom as_json to serializable_hash 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200#issuecomment-3131652

Answer (score 9):

As acknowledged above, this is an issue with the Rails base. The rails patch [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200) is not yet applied and seems at least slightly controversial, so I'm hesitant to apply it locally. Even if applied as a monkey patch it could potentially complicate future rails upgrades.

I'm still considering [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) suggested above, it looks useful. For the moment, I'd rather not add another view templating language into my app. My current needs are very small.

So here's a workaround which doesn't require a patch and work for most simple cases. This works where the association's `as_json` method you'd like to have called looks like

```
def as_json(options={})
  super( <... custom options ...> )
end
```

In my case I've got `Schedule` model which has many `Events`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # define json options as constant, or you could return them from a method
  EVENT_JSON_OPTS = { :include => { :locations => { :only => [:id], :methods => [:name] } } }

  def as_json(options={})
    super(EVENT_JSON_OPTS)
  end
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  def as_json(options={})
    super(:include => { :events => { Event::EVENT_JSON_OPTS } })
  end
end
```

If you followed the guideline that anytime you `:include` an association in your `as_json()` methods, you define any options you need as a constant in the model to be referenced, this would work for arbitrary levels of associations. **NOTE** I only needed the first level of association customized in the above example.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that serializable_hash works just as you'd expect as_json to work, and is always called:

```
  def serializable_hash(options = {})
    result = super(options)
    result[:url] = "http://.."
    result
  end
```

Comment: This is the actual solution to the problem. The bug/'feature' is still there in Rails 5.1 and it doesn't look like it will be fixed.

Comment: My testing on rails 5.1.4 suggests that this is no longer true.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I wanted this to work:

```
render :json => @favorites.as_json(:include => :location)
```

But it didn't so I ended up adding an index.json.erb with the following:

```
<% favs = @favorites.as_json.each do |fav| %>
    <% fav["location"] = Location.find(fav["location_id"]).as_json %>
<% end %>
<%= favs.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Not a fix - just a work around.  I imagine you did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** @John pointed out this is a known bug in Rails. A patch to fix it appears to be: at https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200. Nevertheless, you might try RABL, because its sweet.

I've always been **frustrated with passing a complex set of options** to create the JSON views I want. Your problem, which I experienced with Mongoid in Rails 3.0.9, prompted me to write JSON templates. But actually, if you're dealing with relations or custom api properties, it turns out that **templates are way nicer.**

Besides, dealing with different outputs seems like the View layer to me, so **I settled on using [RABL](http://www.rubyflow.com/items/5649-rabl-the-ruby-api-templating-language), the API templating language.** It makes it super easy to build valid JSON and include any associations or fields.

Not a solution to the problem, but a better solution for the use case.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported as a bug: http://ternarylabs.com/2010/09/07/migrating-to-rails-3-0-gotchas-as_json-bug/

Comment: That's actually a different bug (it's not specifically about associated models), and was fixed in 3.0.2.